# IOS Objective C ARC Conversion Issue

Tags: objective-c

I am busy converting my Objective C code to ARC (Automatic reference counting), and ran into the following issue:

Cast of 'NSInteger' (aka 'int') to 'SomeRandomObject' is disallowed with ARC.

Now in our application we've (unfortunately) been using the tag NSInteger property e.g. located on UITextField, UISwitch etc, to link objects to controls.

e.g.

```
Field *field = [[Field alloc] init...
UITextField *textField = [[UITextField alloc]....
textField.tag = (NSInteger)field;
```

sooo when the code reaches an event you can simply do this

```
UITextField *textField = (UITextField*)sender;
Field *field = (Field*)textField.tag; // ARC hates this
```

What would be a more standard/better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way would be to subclass UITextField and add the properties you want it to have. If you absolutely need to add properties to an object whose class you can't control, you can use [`objc_setAssociatedObject()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_setAssociatedObject) and friends — it's kind of low-level and maybe a bit hacky, but certainly less so than overloading the `tag` property.

Comment: Probably something I can do using a category as well?

Comment: @Helix: You could use a category in conjunction with `objc_setAssociatedObject()` or have a static NSMutableDictionary of UITextField->Field associations in a category, but the category would basically be a "nicer" interface on the solution — it doesn't really solve the problem itself. (The reason I didn't mention the NSDictionary solution is that I really can't think of anything to recommend it over `objc_setAssociatedObject()` and it involves quite a bit more complexity.)

Comment: Yes I agree, the NSDictionary solution would introduce unneeded complexity

Comment: @Helix: And to be clear, I think just making a subclass is the best option if it's available. It's the best-supported and most explicit way to do what you want. The other ways don't offer much except to make more work for you. I just mention `objc_setAssociatedObject()` because sometimes you can't easily subclass.

Comment: I will go with the subclassing option

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if there is a standard way to do what you're after, but you could subclass `UITextField` with a `Field` property.

Alternatively, you can have some `NSDictionary` of `Field`s and use some unique identifier for your `tag` property.

Comment: Both are options I've been considering, since I need to maintain the relationship between my objects

Answer (score 2):

As an example of what @Chuck was talking about, here is a simple implementation of such a thing using a category:

```
@interface UITextField(fieldAdditions)

@property(strong, nonatomic) id field;

@end

@implementation UITextField(fieldAdditions)

-(id) field
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @"field");
}

-(void) setField:(id)field
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @"field", field, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to what chuck was saying which is more correct than what I previously posted.

You can add a category on NSObject:

```
- (void) associateValue:(id)value withKey:(NSString *)aKey {

    objc_setAssociatedObject( self, (__bridge void *)aKey, value, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );
}

- (id) associatedValueForKey:(NSString *)aKey {

    return objc_getAssociatedObject( self, (__bridge void *)aKey );
}
```

Comment: remember to typedef Field to NSNumber

Comment: No, the problem is that you're not supposed to store object references in non-object types under ARC, because the compiler can't tell what you're doing and might release the object prematurely.

Comment: This will never work, nsnumber pointer is not just equal to the number

Comment: Yup @Chuck thats exactly the issue

Comment: Yeah I see that now, I will revise based on Chuck's answer